# this loop does not loop like i want it to. i want it to loop until there is a valid input

Tags: python

this loop does not work as it does on another while loop I made that is almost identical to this one. I want it to loop until I input a valid answer. it asks me the first time and if I get it wrong it asks me one more time, but then it doesn't repeat after that. variable "a" never changes unless a valid input is put in. what did I do wrong?         EDIT: first time using this site and I guess I wasn't specific enough, here is the full code with some fixed changes

```
selectcharacter = input("Select Your Character:")
while a == 1:
    if selectcharacter != 1 and selectcharacter != 2 and selectcharacter != 3:
        selectcharacter = input("Select Your Character:")
        continue
elif: selectcharacter == 1
    a == 2
    break
elif: selectcharacter == 2
    a == 2
    break
elif: selectcharacter == 3
    a == 2
    break
```

Comment: Are comparing a `string` to an `int`?

Comment: `a` never changes, period. Also, `input` returns a `str` value, not an `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: the rest of the code is too long to put in, but under it says if a valid answer is put in, a == 2. that part works fine. i switched the input to raw inputs and it made it to where it doesn't ever ask again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are calling `input` twice in the body of the loop; let the loop condition do its job.

```
select_character = "0"
while select_character not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    select_character = input("Select your character: ")

select_character = int(select_character)  # If you really want an int
```

If you don't want to explicitly initialize `select_character`, use an infinite loop with an explicit break, guarded by a condition you check *after* you call `input`.

```
while True:
    select_character = input("Select your character:" )
    if select_character in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the purpose of variable `a` is, and why you are comparing it to `1`. I think you want a `while True` loop, and `break` out of it once a valid response is made. The user can provide a number between 1-3 (best case scenario), in which case it will successfully cast into an `int` below and reach the `break` line and exit the while loop. If the user provides a number outside of that range, the loop will continue to ask for a character selection. If the user mistakenly provides a non-integer value, it cannot be cast into an `int`, and when tried it will raise a `ValueError` for trying to convert a string into an int. The loop will then enter the `except` block and inform the user of the mistake and `continue`, meaning it will go back to the top of the loop.

```
while True:
    selectCharacter = input('Select your character:')
    # input() returns a str, must cast it to an int. 
    # Use try/except block to ensure the user provided an integer
    try:
        selectCharacter = int(selectCharacter)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer only!')
        continue
    if selectCharacter >= 1 and selectCharacter < 4:
        print('Character selected')
        break
```